# In TypeScript how to define a (generic) type where some properties are defined (but still can be null)?

Tags: typescript

I want (but I can't) defined a generic type that make some properties of `Product` defined, but still nullable. I'm considering myself still learning TypeScript... but it seems so hard to me.

```ts
class Product {
  id: number | string;
  name: null | string;
  variants?: ProductVariant[];
}
```

Here is what I've done so far:

```ts
// Not good: undefined are still allowed
type Exploded<T, K extends string & keyof T> 
  = Omit<T, K> & Required<{ [key in K]: T[key] }>
```

[image]

```ts
// Not good: name is now not null
type Exploded<T, K extends string & keyof T> 
  = Omit<T, K> & Required<{ [key in K]: NonNullable<T[key]> }>
```

[image]

```ts
// Not good: does not handle null AND undefined
type Exploded<T, K extends string & keyof T> 
  = Omit<T, K> & Required<{ 
      [key in K]: null extends T[key] ? T[key] :NonNullable<T[key]> 
    }>
```

Comment: I think that you should use `Pick`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys

Comment: @NirG Pick will left the property as-is (undefined), I may be wrong but I've tested right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Pick` utility type, as suggested by NirG in the question comments, but combined with `Required`:

```
type Exploded<T, K extends keyof T> = Required<Pick<T, K>>;

type ExplodedProduct = Exploded<Product, 'id' | 'name' | 'variants'>;
//   ^? { id: number | string; name: null | string; variants: ProductVariant[]; }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCwBqcUwc4yA3gFDK3IwYYBcyARowDYRkDcVAvlSqhIsRCnTY8YSjTrAsLEDgC2raMgA+yAM5gSIAOZ86yEHBUQlODhy279oY3NoA3YqXA6A-C0m58IhIyMABtAF0+QSowAE8ABxQAUQAPeI5sCCwAHgAVABpkAGlkCBTIECwdZABrCFiMGGRcgD5kAF5kACUIAEccYCgs7NRgBBq8wqKWlr4YhOS0jKws-2kO5FT0zJy1-EKAcgUD+wPzSxPtA-dgrwPZqgB6R7oAPW8qIA)

Comment: I may have omitted that the propeties not listed in Exploded should be leaved as is... but I think it's easly solved with Omit<T, K> & Required...

Comment: Oh your `Omit` makes sense now! ;-) Indeed just add it with an intersection to keep other properties untouched.